# RSpec - Check whether method was called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My goal is to write rspec test that check whether method was called.

```
notify(result) if notification_allowed?(result)
```

Both notification_allowed? and notify are private methods. More precisely I need a test that check whether notify method has was called. I've tried to do something like below but it doesn't seem to be right.

```
subject { described_class.new }

it do
  expect(subject).to receive(:notify)
  subject.send(:notification_allowed?, true)
end
```

Comment: Just sending `notification_allowed?` won't magically make the conditional run. You need to call whatever it is that calls `notify`.

Comment: could you give some example?

Comment: Why do you need to test private methods? Testing methods that are not exposed in the first place might be a sign of approaching the problem in a wrong way. Can you share more code and use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `notification_allowed?` doesn't do anything except return the result of `notification_allowed?`  It's not related to `notify`

You would need to call the function that contains the expression you want to test.

For example, the method might be...

```
def check_and_notify(result)
  notify(result) if notification_allowed?(result)
end
```

so the test would be...

```
subject { described_class.new }

it 'calls notify' do
  expect(subject).to receive(:notify)
  subject.send(:check_and_notify, true)
end
```

Comment: isn't other way to not create new method?

Comment: I see now! Thank you!